# Shell script to print files if modified after last executed?

Tags: bash, shell

I need to write a Linux shell script which can scans a root directory and prints files which were modified after they were last executed.

For example, if File A executed yesterday and I modify it today, the shell script must print File A. However, if File B executed yesterday and I don't modify it yet, then file B shouldn't be printed.

Answer (score 2):

Your primary problem is tracking when the files were executed.

The trouble is, Linux does not keep separate track of when a file was executed as opposed to when it was read for other purposes (such as backup, or review), so it is going to be extremely tricky to get going.

There are a variety of tricks that could be considered, but none of them are particularly trivial or inviting.  One option might be to enable process accounting.  Another might be to modify each script to record when it is executed.

The 'last accessed' time (or `atime`, or `st_atime`, based on the name of the field in `struct stat` that contains the information) doesn't help you because, as already noted, it is modified whenever the file is read.  Although an executed file would certainly have been accessed, there may be many read accesses that do not execute the file but that do trigger an update of the access time.

With those caveats in place, it may be that the access time is the best that you can do, and your script needs to look for files where the access time is equal to the modify time (which means the file was modified and has not been accessed since it was modified - neither read nor printed nor executed).  It is less than perfect, but it may be the best approximation available, short of a complex execution tracking system.

Once you've got a mechanism in place to track the execution times of files, then you can devise an appropriate means of working out which files were modified since they were last executed.

Comment: It does, in `atime` (but not perfectly - reading the file will also set `atime`, just like executing it will). http://www.brandonhutchinson.com/ctime_atime_mtime.html

Answer (score 0):

It is very hard to do this in shell, simply because it is very hard to get `atime` or `mtime` in a sensible format in shell. Consider moving the routine to a more full-featured language like Ruby or Perl:

```
ruby -e 'puts Dir["**/*"].select{ |file| File.mtime(file) > File.atime(file) }'
```

Use `**/*` for all files in current directory and below, `**/*.rb` for all Ruby scripts in current directory in below, `/*` for all files in root... you get the pattern.

Take note what I wrote in a comment to @JohanthanLeffer: UNIX does not differentiate between reading a file and executing it. Thus, printing the script out with `cat ./script` will have the same effect as executing it with `./script`, as far as this procedure is concerned. There is no way to differentiate reading and executing that I can think of, short of making your own kernel.

However, in most cases, you probably won't read the executables; and if you edit them, the save will come after opening, so `mtime` will still trump `atime`. The only bad scenario is if you open a file in an editor then exit without saving it (or just view it with `less`, without modification). As long as you avoid this, the method will work.

Also make note that most editors will not actually modify a file, but create a new file and copy the contents from the old one, then overwrite the old one with the new one. This does not set the `mtime`, but `ctime`. Modify the script accordingly, if this is your usage pattern.

**EDIT**: Apparently, `stat` can help with the sensible representation. This is in `bash`:

```
#!/bin/sh                                                                   

for FILE in `find .`; do
  if [ `stat -f "%m -gt %a" $FILE` ]; then
    echo $FILE
  fi
done
```

Replace `"find ."` (with backticks) with `*` for just current directory, or `/*` for root. To use `ctime` instead of `mtime`, use `%c` instead of `%m`.

Answer (score 0):

Unix system stores 3 time values for any file:

1. last access
2. last modification
3. last change.

I don't think you can get last execution time without using some artificial means, like creating a log or temp file etc. when a executable file runs.

**PS:** Remember not every file in Unix is an executable so that's the reason probably they never thought of storing a file's `last execution timestamp` as well.

However if you do want to get these time values then use:

```
stat -c "%X" file-name # to get last accessed time value as seconds since Epoch
stat -c "%Y" file-name # to get last modified time value as seconds since Epoch
stat -c "%Z" file-name # to get last change time value as seconds since Epoch
```